# How do I keep dictionary both key and value while sorting? (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

```
item = {"num1":[1,3] , "num2": [2,4]}

wanted output

num1:1
num2:2
num1:3
num2:4
```

(basically order by value but some how keep the key it came with
it doesn't have to be in a dictionary as long as the output is order by value)

I'm completely stump atm any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

1. Make pairs(2-tuples) with key-elements.
2. Sort it with second key. (`sorted(target, key=lambda x: x[1])`)

```py
item = {'num1': [1, 3], 'num2': [2, 4]}
result = sorted(
    [
        (k, v)
        for k, list_ in item.items()
        for v in list_
    ],
    key=lambda x: x[1],
)
print(result)
for r in result:
    print(f'{r[0]}:{r[1]}')
```

output:

```
[('num1', 1), ('num2', 2), ('num1', 3), ('num2', 4)]
num1:1
num2:2
num1:3
num2:4
```

@OldBill's solution:

- By reordering elements of tuples, you can use tuple itself for sorting key.
- If you use tuple unpacking in for-loop, it become more readable.

```py
item = {'num1': [1, 3], 'num2': [2, 4]}
result = sorted([
    (v, k)
    for k, list_ in item.items()
    for v in list_
])
print(result)
for v, k in result:
    print(f'{k}:{v}')
```

output:

```
[(1, 'num1'), (2, 'num2'), (3, 'num1'), (4, 'num2')]
num1:1
num2:2
num1:3
num2:4
```

Comment: If you create the tuples as (v, k) you don't need the lambda. Then you just need to swap the indexes used for printing the result

Comment: @OldBill Good point. I'll append your idea into the answer.

Comment: In fact, if you unpack the result as you iterate over it then you don't need to use any list subscripting. e.g., for v, k in result: print(f'{k}:{v}')